# Evaluate $I = ∫∫ 1/((x^2 + y^2)^{n/2}) dxdy$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, circles

Evaluate the double integral

> $$ I = \int\int_D \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)^{n/2}}  dxdy .$$

where $n$ is an integer and $D$ is the region of the plane bounded by two circles centered on the origin and with radii $R_1, R_2$, where $0 < R_1 < R_2$.
Use suitable coordinate system to evaluate $I$, showing the details of the coordinate transformation and how the answer depends on n. Also, for which values of $n$ will the integral converge as $R_1 > 0$ from above?

My friend at university (who is a couple years below me) gave me this question and I haven't got a clue! Not seen one this hard in a long time. Anyone have any ideas? It's annoying me like crazy.

Comment: Polar coordinates should help.

Answer (score 3):

Us polar coordinates, and your integral becomes
$$2\pi \int_{R_1}^{R_2} r^{1-n} d r.$$ This should be easy to do.

Comment: so I integrated to get 2π∫(1/(2-n))*r^2-n without values for R1 and R2 do I just keep in the form R1 and R2 and integrate again?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start. You can use polar coordinates.

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{R_1}^{R_2}\frac{rdrd\theta}{r^{n}} .$$

**Added:** Note that, $n=2$ is a special case, since you will have

> $$ I = 2\pi \int_{R_1}^{R_2}\frac{dr}{r}=2\pi ( \ln(R_1)-\ln(R_1)). $$

Now, find the general case $n\neq 2$.

Comment: so I integrated to get   

2π∫(1/(2-n))*r^2-n  

without values for R1 and R2 do I just keep in the form R1 and R2 and integrate again?